# How to add video and audio tracks to MediaPlaybackItem in Windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

I have a video url and an audio url for the same media. What I want to do is to play them together.

[here in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback-with-mediasource) it's written:

> Using a MediaSource for playback is convenient because it provides a
>   common way to playback media from different kinds of sources, but more
>   advanced behavior can be accessed by creating a MediaPlaybackItem from
>   the MediaSource. This includes the ability to access and manage
>   multiple audio, video, and data tracks for a media item.

And it actually has `VideoTracks` and `AudioTracks` but they are readonly.

```
var videoSource = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(videoUrl));
var mediaPlaybackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(videoSource);
var videoTracks = mediaPlaybackItem.VideoTracks;
```

From where the value of `VideoTracks` collection comes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to do is to play them together.

Actually what you want to do can be implemented by APIs in the [`Windows.Media.Editing namespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn640565). UWP provide [`MediaComposition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.media.editing.mediacomposition.aspx) relative  APIs to enable the users to create media compositions from audio and video source files. Details for how to do please reference [Add a background audio track to a composition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-compositions-and-editing#add-a-background-audio-track-to-a-composition). And you can find a sample from scenario 3 of [MediaEditing official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MediaEditing). Additionally, since you are trying to edit the media, you may need to have access permission for the media file, so you may need to download the file by the url to local firstly.

> How to add video and audio tracks to MediaPlaybackItem in Windows 10

As far as I known, currently there is no APIs support adding video and audio tracks to [`MediaPlaybackItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn930939). As you known, [`MediaPlaybackItem.VideoTracks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybackitem.videotracks) and [`MediaPlaybackItem.AudioTracks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybackitem.audiotracks) are read only, which are for getting the `VideoTracks` and `AudioTracks` from the media which already contains video and audio tracks.

> From where the value of VideoTracks collection comes?

In the screnario 4 of the [VideoPlayback official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/VideoPlayback), it invoke `MediaPlaybackItem.VideoTracks` method to change video track. This sample use a special media source that itself contains multiply track videos. I think these tracks are make by media edit tools. More details you can reference the sample.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand from your answer that `MediaPlaybackItem` is of no use for my purpose because tracks need to be bundled in the file already. and `MediaComposition` needs the files to be local. I think I'll have to sync two `MediaPlayer`s manually for online media playback.

Comment: I wish they could implement [MediaTimelineController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer#use-mediatimelinecontroller-to-synchronize-content-across-multiple-players) for earlier versions of Windows 10 too.